# Malformed inclusion path for Meteor Ionic

Tags: meteor, ionic-framework

I am trying to set up my Meteor app with Ionic (using `meteoric:ionic`). I followed the instructions given (@import statements), also accounting for the known issue with the files being copied only on the second run. Still, I get this error:

```
=> Errors prevented startup:

   While processing files with fourseven:scss (for target web.browser):
   /client/style/app.scss: Scss compiler error: File to import:
   {}/client/style/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/assets/packages/meteoric_ionic-sass/_ionic
   not found in file: /Users/me/repos/brkn/{}/client/style/app.scss


   While processing files with fourseven:scss (for target web.cordova):
   /client/style/app.scss: Scss compiler error: File to import:
   {}/client/style/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/assets/packages/meteoric_ionic-sass/_ionic
   not found in file: /Users/me/repos/brkn/{}/client/style/app.scss


=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
```

Somehow, all paths are prepended by {}/client/style/, which is the location of my app.scss file (can't explain the curly braces).

Can anyone tell what may cause this? How would I fix it?

Comment: i have a sample project with completed instructions here - https://github.com/aaronksaunders/meteor-ionic-demo2

Answer (score 0):

That repo is no longer maintained.

Please use this official ionic package for meteor `meteor add driftyco:ionic`